# Problem checking if an item exists in cart

Tags: reactjs

hello I've been having a problem with checking if an item already exists in the cart. if so I want only the quantity to be updated for some reason it keeps adding the item as a new item even if it exists. This is what I've been doing:

```
  // Adding Items to cart
  const onAdd = (product, quantity) => {
  const checkProductInCart = cartItemsFromLocalStorage.find((item) => item.id === product.id);

  setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => (prevTotalPrice + Math.round((product.price * quantity)*100)/100));
  setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + quantity);


 if(checkProductInCart) {
   // eslint-disable-next-line
  const updatedCartItems = cartItemsFromLocalStorage.map((cartProduct) => {
    if(cartProduct.id === product.id) return {
      ...cartProduct,
      quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
    }
    
  })

  setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
} else {
  product.quantity = quantity;
  

  setCartItems([{ ...product }, ...cartItems]);
}

toast.success(` ${product.name} added to the cart.`);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue is on your `cartItemsFromLocalStorage.map` implementation. The map function should return the product even if it isn't the one you're looking to update. Try updating that map to

```js
cartItemsFromLocalStorage.map((productOnCart) => {
  if (productOnCart.id === product.id) {
    return { ...productOnCart, cartProduct.quantity + quantity }
  }
  return productOnCart
})
```

If you don't return anything your list will be full of `undefined` objects